# Angular $resource with large dataset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, resources

Hi I have some angular code that utilises $resource to call a web api and get back some data. All works fine until the dataset being returned from the api gets over a few thousand rows. I get a really unhelpful error as detailed below:

Error: [$resource:badcfg] array
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$resource/badcfg?p0=object

I'm calling with GET, isArray: true and with some headers which just contain dates.

Anyone encountered this sort of problem?

Comment: are you passing whole date object through url? it will pass as `[Object][Object]`

Comment: Yes the whole date object is sent

Comment: All works fine until more than 2 thousands rows are being returned, I'll post the code when I have access to it again

Comment: 'var result =  $resource(SettingsService.getAPIURL() + classname + '/', {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: params, isArray: true, headers: headers }
            });'

Comment: The issue was actually to do with the data being returned. I had a string that was getting encoded as a number due to formatting of the string. The string was 180E26 which was being treated as a large number and encoded that way eg 1.8e+26.

So not really an Angular issue but more to do with the PHP API that was being called along with the data.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the $resource complained that your api returned something it doesn't like. In this case, the api returned an object when $resource expected array.

If you are making request and expect an object, you should use {method:'GET'}

using {method:'GET', isArray:true} only when you are expecting an array

You are getting an object {} back from your api, so you should not have "isArray:true"

Comment: I had a number being treated as an infinite number which is what angular didn't like. As there were some strings that started with E180 they were treated as huge numbers by the API and an error was being thrown